# Get "ClassNotFoundException when using HttpClientBuilder

Tags: java, http

Old programmer, new to Java. I am trying to run what I think is pretty common example code that is similar in a number of places on the web, `HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()` throws an exception and I can't figure out why.  I'm using HttpClient 4.3.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ATest{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String strURL  = "http://192.9.10.11/cgi-bin/echo";
      String message = "hello world";
      // next line throwsClassNotFoundException, why?
      HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
      HttpPost   httpPost   = new  HttpPost(strURL);
      httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(message));
      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      try {
         System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         // do something useful with the response body
         // and ensure it is fully consumed
         EntityUtils.consume(entity);
      } finally {
         response.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: A `ClassNotFoundException` occurs when your application classpath does not contain the specified class. How are you running your application?

Answer (score 6):

The Java VM comes with a lot of classes but not `org.apache.http.*`.

You have to help the Java VM, like you help gcc to link a binary in C or C++ with `-lxxx` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, with the classpath notion. `java -cp <path>:<path>:<path>` specify where are the classes needed (like the .so for binaries under Unix).

`org.apache.http.*` classes are located into a jar. you have to specify this jar path into `cp <path>` spec.

The jars contained in the [apache http client 4.3 delivery](http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3-bin.zip) are located in the lib directory:

- httpclient-4.3.jar
- httpmime-4.3.jar
- fluent-hc-4.3.jar
- httpclient-cache-4.3.jar
- httpcore-4.3.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- commons-codec-1.6.jar

You don't need all if your code is just a sample, I suggest `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar` and `httpclient-4.3.jar`

Comment: I see, i needed more (all) of the apache jars from the zip file.  Duh, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the below dependency in your build.gradle app module

> compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'